# ypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at db.collection.findOne (nature of error has changed)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As the title suggests, I am getting the following error when using the findOne function in one of my back-end routes:

```
/home/liam/Documents/aiRegister/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:123
process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at db.collection.findOne (/home/liam/Documents/aiRegister/app/routes

/user_routes.js:14:16)
    at handleCallback (/home/liam/Documents/aiRegister/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:120:56)
    at /home/liam/Documents/aiRegister/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1416:5
    at handleCallback (/home/liam/Documents/aiRegister/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:120:56)
    at /home/liam/Documents/aiRegister/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:683:5
    at handleCallback (/home/liam/Documents/aiRegister/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:171:5)
    at setCursorNotified (/home/liam/Documents/aiRegister/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:515:3)
    at /home/liam/Documents/aiRegister/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:599:16
    at queryCallback (/home/liam/Documents/aiRegister/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:232:18)
    at /home/liam/Documents/aiRegister/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:18
```

Here is my code:

```
   //Get user
  app.get('/user/:token', (req, res) => {
    const details = {
      'token': req.params.token
    };
    db.collection('users').findOne(details, (err, item) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send({
          'error': 'An error has occurred'
        });
      } else {
        delete item.token;
        res.send(item);
      }
    });
  });
```

I have updated npm and node and all installed packages, with no luck. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: It seems that the error comes from the 'delete item.token;' because, as it turns out, the document does not exist. However, this raises the question of why the document does not exist, even though it is being added (or so I thought. It turns out that the route to add a user is not running, but is returning a success to my front end. Here is the code:

```
//Add user
  app.post('/user', (req, res) => {
    const user = {
      email: req.body.email,
      name: req.body.name,
      token: req.body.token
    };
    const details = {
      email: req.body.email
    };
    console.log("Adding user...");
    db.collection('users').remove(details, (err, item) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send({
          'error': 'An error has occurred'
        });
      } else {
        console.log("User del...");
      }
    });
    db.collection('users').insert(user, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send({
          'error': 'An error has occurred'
        });
      } else {
        res.send(result.ops[0]);
        console.log("User added");
      }
    });
  });
```

And on my front-end:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "/api/user",
      data: {
        name: user["displayName"],
        email: user["email"],
        token: token
      },
      success: console.log("Success!")
    });
```

I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Show the code please, not only the stack trace.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Will edit

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. 
With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. 
This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Nick Please see my edits